# Can I use a custom serialize (remove properties) with JSON.Net at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have an object that I need to serialize, and this object has another object inside it on which I need to filter the properties to remove some. For example:

```
class inner {
    string baz = "hi";
    string blah = "hide me";
}

class outer {
    int foo = 7;
    inner bar = new inner();
}
```

I was able to use a `ContractResolver`, but (as far as I know) that requires serializing the `inner` object separately, which in turn shows up as an escaped JSON string rather than part of the `outer` object, i.e.:

```
{"foo":7,"bar":"{\"baz\":\"hi\"}"}
```

What I need is:

```
{"foo":7,"bar":{"baz":"hi"}} // no blah property
```

I thought about using a custom JsonConverter, but wasn't sure how to use that converter only for the `inner` object or "pass through" everything else and only run my custom filtering on the `inner` object.

I can't do it with attribute (AFAIK) because elsewhere I want to serialize the whole `inner` object and that's an all-or-nothing setting. (Unless maybe I add it at runtime?) Also, in the event something else has a `blah` property, I don't want to remove that...only from the `inner` type.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you use properties instead of fields you can just use attributes to skip serialization. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom converter. Something like this:

```
    public class InnerSerializer : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(inner);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var inner = value as inner;
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("baz");
            writer.WriteValue(inner.baz);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
```

Then if you want to use it, add it as argument to `SerializeObject`:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new outer(), new InnerSerializer());
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, I think. So if my custom converter returns false in CanConvert, it will just fall back to using the default converter?

Answer (score 0):

My solution about serialize json all time is dynamic object. I mean I am not using class. I am creating dynamic object for my neccesary field and I am serializing that dynamic object. So sometimes I don't need all field of my class and I am just putting necessary field to dynamic object. This is an very simple example.

```
class inner 
{
   string baz = "hi";
   string blah = "hide me";
}

class outer 
{
   int foo = 7;
   inner bar = new inner();
}
dynamic dyn = new {
   foo = outer.foo,
   bar = inner
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dyn);
```

Hope this help.